# Can the Chat ID of a Telegram user be changed?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

It is known that the `chat_id` of a Telegram user uniquely identifies that person. But are there any circumstances under which this ID can be changed?

I plan to use the `chat_id` (obtained through a bot) for user verification. The purpose of this is to prevent duplicate accounts. I expect this to have the same reliability as phone number verification but without the associated costs.

For this to work, there must be 1 `chat_id` per phone number but I couldn't find clear information on this.

Comment: why not use `user_id`?

Comment: "Telegram Chat ID is an unique identification number of a Telegram chat(personal/group chat). However the Telegram User ID is a unique identification number of a particular Telegram user. Telegram Chat ID helps telegram to identify your Telegram chat groups even if you change name and username of Telegram Group." https://innovativebeast.com/difference-between-telegram-chat-id-and-user-id/

Comment: For simplicity because `chat_id` is already being used to send messages to the user as well. But that seems like a viable solution. Thanks!